# Windows account for IIS7 to connect DB

Tags: windows, wcf, authentication, iis-7, hosting

I have Client, WCF service (hosted in windows service) and Object Database. To connect Object DB we have one API provided by DB team. This API reads the Windows account posted in Windows hosted Logon Account.

Is there any way I can give same Windows account into IIS 7.0 so that I can able to connect to our Object based DB.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager you should find the Application Pool that your application runs in. Then in Advanced Settings dialog you can set Process Model - Identity to a custom user account.

[Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) is a detailed description of what you must do.